# Sum of sum of elementary s of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation

Let n ≥ 1 be an integer. For each subset S ⊂ {1,2,...,3n}, let f (S) be the sum of the elements of S, with f  (ø) = 0.
Determine, as a function of n, the sum
∑
f (S) S ⊂{1,2,...,3n }
3|f (S)
where S runs through all subsets of {1,2,...,3n} such that f (S) is a multiple of 3.
Please help me , im really stuck on this one , maybe its induction , but idk how to find the general formula for n , the case n=1,2,3 are trivial

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial for formatting on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer but here's a approach that might help: Let $A=\{1,...,3n\}$ and let $M = \{S\subset A : f(S) \text{ is a multiple of } 3\}$. Notice that for any $S \subset A$ we have $f(S) + f(S^c) = f(A) = 3n(3n+1)/2$. Hence $S \in M\iff S^c \in M$, so
$$\sum_{S\in M} f(S) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{S\in M} \left[f(S) + f(S^c)\right]$$
$$= \frac{3n(3n+1)}{4}\big|M\big|$$

So the problem is equivalent to finding the size of the set $M$. I don't know if that's easier.

Comment: Sorry , what does S^c means?

Comment: @Ak04 $S^c$ is the complement of the set $S$